# How to run a bash script from jsp page ? (All are in a .war file of my web application)

Tags: bash, jakarta-ee, executable, war

I have a bash script inside  my .war file & i want to call it to run from my web page(probably jsp).How can i do that?
The bash script uses root privilages.I will call it with gksudo.Can that be done?Is .war file writable?I use Tomcat.

Comment: First, you need to ask a question, even if it's just "How do I do that?" Second, that frankly sounds like a terrible idea and you're unlikely to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is [a .war file](http://www.beanshell.org/bshservlet.html) that is part of the Beanshell project and that .war is capable of running Beanshell scripts in Java code, which means you could do pretty much anything.

There might be better ways of doing this but this is all I know right now.